# putting data from database to label.text

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I call setText method it wont return anything.

```
setText("Sprite", "lblSpriteQty.Text", "lblSpriteTP.Text", 15)
```

Code I use for method setText

```
 Public Sub setText(ByVal productname As String, ByVal qty As String, ByVal tp As String, ByVal price As Integer)

    Using cs As New SqlConnection("Data Source=KARL-PC;Initial Catalog=ShawarmaToldb;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM [tblOrderDetails] WHERE productid = (SELECT productid FROM [tblProduct] WHERE productname = @productname)", cs)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", productname)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cs.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                If IsDBNull(dr.GetValue(0)) Then
                    qty = "0" 'but if i put lblSpriteQty.Text instead of qty it's working
                    tp = "0" 'same as here
                Else
                    qty = dr.GetValue(0).ToString
                    tp = dr.GetValue(0).ToString * price
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you are modifying a local variable instead of returning qty and tp to the caller. Instead either set the text in this method or make it a `Function` that returns an `Integer` for the quantity.

Comment: setText method does not have return type.

Comment: You are directly assigning text to a label within while loop that why it is working

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying  local variables(the method arguments) instead of returning `qty` and `tp` to the calling method. But even if you made them `ByRef` you couldn't change them since strings are immutable. Instead either set the text in this method or make it a `Function` that returns an `Integer` for the quantity which is all that you need.

```
Public Function GetSumQuantity(ByVal productname As String) As Integer
    Using cs As New SqlConnection("Data Source=KARL-PC;Initial Catalog=ShawarmaToldb;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM [tblOrderDetails] WHERE productid = (SELECT productid FROM [tblProduct] WHERE productname = @productname)", cs)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", productname)
            cs.Open()
            Dim sumQuantityObj = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            If DbNull.Value = sumQuantityObj Then Return 0
            Return DirectCast(sumQuantityObj, Integer)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Now you can calculate the value and assign it to the label's text in the calling method:

```
Dim sumQuantity As Integer = GetSumQuantity("IPhone")
Dim tp = price * sumQuantity 
lblSpriteQty.Text = tp.ToString()
```